# Filtering choices in many to many relationship

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Today I am having a problem in MS Access 2013 with a many to many relationship. I have a many to many relationship set up with a junction table which works great but I am trying to filter the results of the choices based on the relationships from one side of the many to many. I know this sounds confusing but here is the example of my database.
[image: Relationship Table]

And here is an example form.

[image: Form Example]

Lets say I have comboboxes that link to table 1 and Table 2 and properly limit those selections. How would I go about limiting the available selection of level 3 records within the subform based on the Selections made from other tables?

I hope that wasnt too confusing. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the order in which the comboboxes will be selected?

Answer (score 0):

So i actually solved this one myself. Instead of a datasheet for the subform i changed it to a continuous form then used unbound combo boxes to pull the entries from the other tables and based on the selections filteres what was shown as available selections for the junction table subform.